# How often do different breeds of dog poop?

Tags: dogs, defecation

Small parrots poop much more frequently than large parrots. I have never had (or lived with) a dog. I would like to know how often dogs need to poop and especially whether pooping frequency is related to breed size.

Comment: some years ago it was found that all mamals use about the same time when peeing so a mouse use about the same time as an elephant to empty the bladder.

Comment: Related [Do small parrots poop more frequently than large parrots?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19539/do-small-parrots-poop-more-frequently-than-large-parrots)

Answer (score 5):

My experience is 1-3 poops a day.  Big dogs just take bigger poops.

Comment: Seems to fit with my experience. With a caveat that diet influences frequency and fluidity.