# Do small parrots poop more frequently than large parrots?

Tags: birds, parrots, defecation

A recent [post said:](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19531/how-often-do-different-breeds-of-dog-poop)

> Small parrots poop much more frequently than large parrots.

Is that actually true? If so why?

Answer (score 3):

From my personal experience, the answer to your question is yes. As fmorales mentioned within their answer, the smaller the bird the faster the food gets digested. I have also read and know for a fact that a budgie will usually poop every 15 mins and while an amazon can poop around 30-45 minutes. I have taken care of a Red Lored Amazon Parrot and multiple budgies(american Parakeet) within my life.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, little birds poop more often than big birds.There are several reasons.

- The smaller the bird, the faster the metabolism
- Smaller birds have have faster transit time though the intestines
- Little birds have a smaller 'holding tank'.

Comment: This answer could be improved with a reference or two.  As written it sounds like an opinion reflecting what is quoted in the question.